# New Angular quickstart seed gives npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to node.js, npm and Angular.  I'm trying to setup a new Angular 2 project with their provided quickstart seed.

I'm following the `Setup for local development` instructions from angular.io
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
```

I get a few warnings but the most concerning is:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

To see what relies on `minimatch@0.3.0` I run:

```
npm ls minimatch
```

And I get:

```
├─┬ karma@1.4.1
│ └── minimatch@3.0.3 
└─┬ protractor@4.0.14
  └─┬ jasmine@2.4.1
    └─┬ glob@3.2.11
      └── minimatch@0.3.0
```

So I think I need to update protractor which is depending on the old minimatch version?

```
npm install protractor@latest --save
```

But this gives me:

```
WARN engine protractor@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=6.9.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
```

And now:

```
npm ls protractor
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 /path/to/project/
└── protractor@5.0.0 invalid
npm ERR! invalid: protractor@5.0.0 /path/to/project/module
```

Node and npm are already the latest version available from the Ubuntu Xenial repo.

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade nodejs
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1).
apt-get install --only-upgrade npm
npm is already the newest version (3.5.2-0ubuntu4).
```

Concern 1:
For each Angular project do I really need to run npm install on the quickstart seed?  It downloads ~100mb of modules and I'm on limited bandwidth.  It seems ridiculous to require 100mb of modules to start a simple empty project.

Concern 2:
Using the Angular provided quickstart seed, npm installs minimatch 0.3.0 module which has a DoS security vulnerability.  Is it expected to compile the latest node.js and npm from source first in order to get the latest module versions?

Concern 3:
This all seems like a lot of overheard compared to simply including one js file like you would with other javascript frameworks or libraries.  Is it worth doing all this to use Angular and write in TypeScript which needs to convert into javascript?  Angular 2 was a complete rewrite which is one reason I have doubts about trying to keep up with the latest and greatest best practices.

Answer (score 0):

To *Concern 1*:
No you don't need to. The *quickstart seed* is as it says, is a *seed* so just a convenient way to setup a new project with a lot of tools and goodies preconfigured. The *@angular* packages and some polyfills, zone.js and rxjs are the only "real" dependencies and i don't think it hits the 15mb mark, but i didn't check to be honest. Angular2 node_modules are about 10mb in size.

To *Concern 2*:
As you already saw yourself, this is a dependency used by *karma* and *protractor*, two testing tools / runner which have nothing to do with Angular2 itself. You wouldn't deploy the modules anyway so there is no problem in using it.

To *Concern 3*:
It's a little bit more than just a single javascript file and Typescript is preferred and you're adviced to use it, but you don't have to. You could write angular2 in plain JS or Dart. 
Don't know any developer who dived into Typescript and regretted it though, but this is very opinion based.

Hope i could clear up your concerns at least a bit.